# ¿Cómo usar una variable para almacenar una impresión general y costumizarla dependiendo de lo que se necesite imprimir, en Python?

Tags: python

Tengo este código:

```
for team_name in teams: 
        text = "Members of the group {0}, \
             status of the group {1},\
             date when the group was created {2}, \
             list of tasks available for the group"
        if team_name['name'] == "Vikings":
           return text.format(team_name['members'], team_name['status'], team_name['dateCreated'],team_name['listTasks'])
        elif team_name == "Fighters":
            return text.format(team_name['members'], team_name['status'], team_name['dateCreated'],team_name['listTasks'])
```

Me gustaría que la variable *text* almacene lo general y que luego dependiendo de la condición imprima ese mismo mensaje pero con los atributos que le corresponde a esa condición.

Comment: No se entiende lo que pides. Ambas ramas del `if` hacen lo mismo.

Comment: Viniste aqui y dijiste lo que querias hacer. Ahora, cual seria la duda? Como hacerlo? Si es eso, viendo que tu codigo tiene return, supongo que es un fragmento de una funcion. Entonces, por que no haces print(lafuncion(arg1, arg2, ...))? Pero todo eso se basa en una serie de adivinanzas. Te recomiendo ser mas directo con tus dudas.

Comment: mi duda es como hacer un print costumizable para esos dos if, sin tener que hacer un print de esto en cada if  text = "Members of the group {0}, \
             status of the group {1},\
             date when the group was created {2}, \
             list of tasks available for the group"..format(team_name['members'], team_name['status'], team_name['dateCreated'],team_name['listTasks']) " @DanteS.

Comment: En ese caso estás en buen camino. Por que no intentas con mi propuesta? Algo que no funcione o no sirva?

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso `text` es una variable tipo "plantilla", no necesitas repetirla en cada iteración del `for`.

Usaré una versión más corta para entender más fácil y escribir menos. Suponiendo que se tiene la siguiente data de ejemplo:

```py
teams = [
    {'name':'nombre1', 'members':'miembros1'}, 
    {'name':'nombre2', 'members':'miembros2'}, 
    {'name':'nombreN', 'members':'miembrosN'}
]

text1 = "Grupo {0}, grupo {1}" # plantilla 1 (posicional)
text2 = "Grupo {name}, grupo {members}" # plantilla 2 (indexada)
```

Para imprimir todas los valores en las plantillas:

```py
for g in teams:
    print(text1.format(g['name'], g['members']))
    print(text2.format(name=g['name'], members=g['members']))
```

O lo que es lo mismo (Ver [unpacking](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+args+kwargs)):

```py
for g in teams:
    print(text1.format(*(g.values())))
    print(text2.format(**g))
```

Ambos códigos arrojarán la siguiente salida:

```
Grupo nombre1, grupo miembros1
Grupo nombre1, grupo miembros1
Grupo nombre2, grupo miembros2
Grupo nombre2, grupo miembros2
Grupo nombreN, grupo miembrosN
Grupo nombreN, grupo miembrosN
```

Si quieres solo imprimir los grupos que cumplen determinada condición y no repetir los `print()`, se puede usar un `if` con condicion múltiple `if (g['name'] == 'nombre1') and (g['name'] == 'nombre2')`, lo malo es que no sería fácil de mantener si hay muchas opciones.
Para paliar un poco esto, se puede usar un `if` normal con `else/continue`. No es muy bonito, será un poco confuso al principio, pero funciona. Lo que hace este código es que si se cumple una condición, evita el `continue` y llega al final de `for` (imprimiendo el valor), de lo contrario (si no cumple) es retornado a la siguiente iteración.

```py
for g in teams:
    if g['name'] == 'nombre1': 
        pass
    elif g['name'] == 'nombre2': 
        pass
    else: 
        continue
    print(text2.format(**g))
```

Lo mismo se puede escribir de una forma más bonita e intuitiva con `in`:

```py
for g in teams:
    if g['name'] in ['nombre1', 'nombre2']:
        print(text2.format(**g))
```

Resultado:

```
Grupo nombre1, grupo miembros1
Grupo nombre2, grupo miembros2
```